# sqlalchemy session problem :there is code :query_device after query will rollback cause outer function ta transaction not commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

there is my code ,query_device after query will rollback cause outer function ta transaction not commit,ho do i solve it

```
engine = create_engine(db_path + "?check_same_thread=False", pool_recycle=True, echo=True)

session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)

def query_device(id_) :
    with Session() as session:
        device = session.query(Device).filter(Device.deviceNumber == id_).first()
    return device


def ta():
    with Session() as session_:

        from api.common_service import get_room_device_id_by_bed
        nurse_ = session_.query(Nurse).filter(Nurse.id == 1).first()
        nurse_.age = 800
        query_device('11f0a51b01060a4a')

        session_.commit()
```

Comment: I don't know much about your code, and I could be wrong; but what I'm curious to know why you need to commit() after the ```query_device``` when you can just commit() and then run query_device() since you aren't even modifying anything.

Comment: this is my test code  sample, my project have same problem ,i just show how cause this problem